# Firebase query hashmap to class

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase, and I'm doing some query to get the data, and then I'm using `addChildEventListener` I also tried `addValueEventListener`to get the result . The response from `dataSnapshot.getValue()` is a `HashMap`.

I found that each key in that `HashMap` (in first case) represents the field in my class.

Is there a faster way to convert that `HashMap` to my class\model? Or do I have to do it custom for each class I have?.

I found in [LINK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) that I can use `dataSnapshot.getValue(Trip.class);`, however, it throws `DataseException`.

My experience with reflection is very little, but I understand in theory I can use it, but not sure how, so if possible an example would appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT**
Trip model for example (not all of it of course just to view it)

```
public class Trip implements Model
{
    private String ID;
    private String driverID;

    private LatLng addressFrom;
    private LatLng addressTo;

    private List<LatLng> locationList;

    private boolean isActive;
}
```

`HashMap` response is like this (while debugging)

```
result = {HashMap@830043578728}  size = 14
 0 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@830043579944} "fullAddress" -> "this is the address"
 1 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@830043579176} "addressFrom" -> " size = 2"
 2 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@830043581632} "state" -> "0"
 3 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@830043579552} "distanceMeter" -> "706"
 4 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@830043580000} "id" -> "-KX5Ihn7E_g8HEmsXXL3"
 5 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@830043579744} "duration" -> "157"
 6 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@830043581864} "timeMilliSeconds" -> "1479722067649"
 7 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@830043579664} "driverID" -> "RZZplHcojGWRoJdRH2SOswQvSBO2"
 8 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@830043579472} "addressTo" -> " size = 2"
 9 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@830043581520} "locationList" -> " size = 3"
 10 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@830043580080} "length" -> "706"
 11 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@830043578880} "active" -> "false"
 12 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@830043581576} "passengerCount" -> "1"
 13 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@830043579800} "endAddressText" -> "this is the end address text"
```

**EDIT 2** (exception from getValue(Trip.lass)

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng is missing a constructor with no arguments

Comment: Can you post your class model and the response hashmap ?

Comment: @rhari please check the edit

Comment: Can you also post the exception that you get in the logcat when using dataSnapshot.getValue(Trip.class); ?

Comment: @rhari I've added the exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error is occurring because some classes like LatLng cannot be stored in Firebase directly. Looking at [this sample app](https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.in/2015/06/code-road-android-app-store-your.html) by google, when the location data is sent to Firebase, the getLatitude() and getLongitude() values are used instead of the LatLng class. So if you use something like List of HashMaps from Lat to Long to store your location data, you can use dataSnapshot.getValue(Trip.class) to parse it.

Comment: thanks. seems that was my issue, i've create another class that is similar to `LatLng`,but with a constructor with no parameters, and used it. Now it works.